# Is it feasible to implement a Uniswap V3 contract integration that can simultaneously call flash and swap on the same pool in a single transaction?

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3, flash-loans, uni

We are considering the development of a Uniswap V3 flash liquidator smart contract. The liquidator will flash an amount of tokens (e.g., USDC) from the Uniswap V3 pool in order to liquidate a lending position with USDC as underlying of the lending position, resulting in receiving collateral in the form of WETH. To repay the flashed USDC, we need to sell some of the liquidated WETH to cover the flash amount plus fee. Our question is whether it is possible to call both the `flash` and `swap` functions on the same pool in the same transaction within our smart contract implementation of the liquidator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing the [UniswapV3Pool](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/05c10bf6d547d6121622ac51c457f93775e1df09/contracts/UniswapV3Pool.sol) smart contract, we can deduce that it is not possible to call both `flash` and `swap` on the same pool in the same transaction.

Upon inspecting the implementation of `flash`, we see that it utilizes the `lock` modifier, which functions as a reentrancy guard that activates the lock at the start of method execution, then deactivates it after execution.

[image]

Upon further examining `swap`, we observe that it requires the reentrancy lock to be disabled to execute the function successfully.

[image]

As a result, since calling `flash` will activate the reentrancy lock and prohibit us from calling any other safeguarded method in the same transaction, we will be unable to call `swap` on the same pool in our implementation of `uniswapV3FlashCallback`. To avoid reentrancy, a common approach with Uniswap V3 flash integrations is to use one pool with a fee tier to call flash, followed by another pool with the same tokens but a different fee tier to call swap.

Example code for reference:

https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/guides/flash-integrations/final-contract